# A conjecture on consistent monotone sequences of polynomials in Bernstein form

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory, conjectures, simulation

### A Conjecture

In the following, a polynomial $P(x)$ is written in *Bernstein form of degree $n$* if it is written as— $$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k {n \choose k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k},$$ where $a_0, ..., a_n$ are the polynomial's *Bernstein coefficients*.  The degree-$n$ *Bernstein polynomial* of an arbitrary function $f(\lambda)$ has Bernstein coefficients $f(k/n)$.  In general, this Bernstein polynomial differs from $f$ even if $f$ is a polynomial.

Let $f(\lambda):[0,1]\to(0,1)$ have $r\ge 1$ continuous derivatives, and denote the Bernstein polynomial of degree $n$ of a function $g$ as $B_n(g)$. Let $W_{2^0}(\lambda), W_{2^1}(\lambda), ..., W_{2^i}(\lambda),...$ be a sequence of functions on [0, 1] that converge uniformly to $f$.

For each integer $n\ge 1$ that's a power of 2, suppose that there is $D>0$ such that— $$|f(\lambda)-B_n(W_n(\lambda))| \le DM/n^{r/2},$$ whenever $0\le \lambda\le 1$ and $M$ is the maximum absolute value of $f$ and its derivatives up to the $r$-th derivative.

Then, a [**conjecture**](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#A_Conjecture_on_Polynomial_Approximation) is that there is $C_0\ge D$ such that for every $C\ge C_0$, there are polynomials $g_n$ and $h_n$ (for each $n\ge 1$) as follows:

1. $g_n$ and $h_n$ have Bernstein coefficients $W_n(k/n) - CM/n^{r/2}$ and $W_n(k/n) + CM/n^{r/2}$, respectively ($0\le k\le n$), if $n$ is a power of 2, and $g_n=g_{n-1}$ and $h_n=h_{n-1}$ otherwise;
2. $\lim_n g_n =\lim_n h_n=f$;
3. $(g_{n+1}-g_{n})$ and $(h_{n}-h_{n+1})$ are polynomials with non-negative Bernstein coefficients once they are rewritten to polynomials in Bernstein form of degree exactly $n+1$.

(2 and 3 correspond to the formal statement above.)

Equivalently (see also Nacu and Peres 2005), there is $C_1>0$ such that, for each integer $n\ge 1$ that's a power of 2— $$\max_{0\le k\le 2n}\left|\left(\sum_{i=0}^k \left(W_n\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\right) {n\choose i}{n\choose {k-i}}/{2n \choose k}\right)-W_{2n}\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right)\right|\le \frac{C_1 M}{n^{r/2}}.$$

It is also conjectured that the same value of $C_0$ (or $C_1$) suffices when $f$ has a Lipschitz continuous $(r-1)$-th derivative and $M$ is the maximum absolute value of $f$ and the Lipschitz constants of $f$ and its derivatives up to the $(r-1)$-th derivative.

Without loss of generality: For what value of $C_0$ is the conjecture true when $W_n = 2 f - B_n(f)$ and $r$ is 3 or 4?  When $W_n$ is arbitrary?

### Background

I asked this question in order to solve the so-called [*Bernoulli factory* problem](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html), described next. We're given a coin that shows heads with an unknown probability, $\lambda$. The goal is to use that coin (and possibly also a fair coin) to build a "new" coin that shows heads with a probability that depends on $\lambda$, call it $f(\lambda)$. This is the *Bernoulli factory problem*, and it can be solved only if $f$ is continuous (Keane and O'Brien 1994).

However, since I asked this question I have found a [Bernoulli factory algorithm](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#Another_General_Algorithm) that I believe is general enough to cover all the cases that this conjecture would help solve.

Since this conjecture may be of broader interest, though, I leave this question open.  See also my [other open questions](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernreq.html) about the Bernoulli factory problem.

### Results

Here are results that correspond to the conjecture.

- If $r=1$ and $W_n=f$, then $C_0 = (1+\sqrt{2})$ (Nacu and Peres 2005), even in the Lipschitz case.
- If $r=2$ and $W_n=f$, then $C_0 = 1/2$ (Nacu and Peres 2005).
- If $r=2$ and $W_n=f$, then $C_0 = 1/7$ for every $n\ge 4$ (see "[Proofs for Polynomial Building Schemes](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#Proofs_for_Polynomial_Building_Schemes)").

Here are some conjectured results (for others see "[A Conjecture on Polynomial Approximation](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#A_Conjecture_on_Polynomial_Approximation)").  They relate to polynomials that achieve a better convergence rate than Bernstein polynomials (namely $O(1/n^{r/2})$ rather than $O(1/n)$), such as linear combinations (Butzer 1953) and iterated Boolean sums (Micchelli 1973) of Bernstein polynomials.

- If $r=3$ and $W_n=2 f - B_n(f)$*, then $C_0 = \frac{3}{16-4 \sqrt{2}}.$
- If $r=5$ and $W_n = B_n(B_n(f))+3(f-B_n(f))$**, then $C_0 = 0.27.$

### References

- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", *ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation* 4(2), 1994.
- Nacu, Şerban, and Yuval Peres. "Fast simulation of new coins from old", The Annals of Applied Probability 15, no. 1A (2005): 93-115.
- C.S. Güntürk, W. Li, "[Approximation of functions with one-bit neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.09181.pdf)", arXiv:2112.09181 [cs.LG], 2021.
- Micchelli, C. (1973). The saturation class and iterates of the Bernstein polynomials. Journal of Approximation Theory, 8(1), 1-18.
- Butzer, P.L., "Linear combinations of Bernstein polynomials", Canadian Journal of Mathematics 15 (1953).

---

* Corresponds to the iterated Boolean sum of order 2 (Güntürk and Li 2021).

*** Corresponds to the iterated Boolean sum of order 3 (Güntürk and Li 2021).

Comment: In point **3.**, $r_n:=g_{n+1}-g_n$ and $s_n:=h_n-h_{n+1}$ are required to be polynomials of degree *exactly equal to*  or *not larger than* $n+1$? And the coefficients of their Bernstein polynomial $B_mr_n$ and $B_ms_n$ of what order $m$ are required to be non-negative?

Comment: @PietroMajer: $r_n$ and $s_n$ -- not their Bernstein polynomials $B_m r_n$ and $B_m s_n$, which are different in general -- must be polynomials and must have non-negative Bernstein coefficients once they are rewritten to polynomials in Bernstein form of degree exactly $n+1$.

Comment: Thank you. But then would you clarify which are the Bernstein coefficients of the above $r_n$ and $s_n$ exactly?

Comment: @PietroMajer: Rewrite $r_n$ and $s_n$ (e.g., from the power basis) to the Bernstein form of degree exactly $n+1$ (see the section "Background"), and then take their coefficients in the Bernstein form. These coefficients (labeled $a_k$ in the section "Background") are the Bernstein coefficients (of degree $n+1$) of $r_n$ and $s_n$.

Comment: Now up to version 19 of this question.